# Database quiz winform with multiple answers

Tags: winforms

when I select radiobutton1 and then radiobutton2 then in the list string it is getting store both the option(radiobutton1 & radiobutton2) and due to which the correct answer marks are not getting calculated properly.

My Oracle database having 2 tables :

1. Questions (tid,question_id,questions,issue_no)

2)answers(tid,issue_no,question_id,answr_id,answers,marks)

I have created a list string array in which I stored the values after user selects an option out 5 radiobuttons. The actual results is that values of radio buttons are getting added multiple in list string array expected is that whenever user selects an option at a time single  value to be added in the list string array. How to achieve this

Comment: For us to be able to help you better, please edit the question and post some code -- absolute minimum required to reproduce the issue you are having.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.